# Find the particular solution of following differential equation that meets the condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the particular solution of following differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2\sqrt{4-y}$

That meets the condition:

$y=2$ and $x=4$

Comment: I have tried to solve the integral with geometrical substitution but I failed because resulting integral is complex to resolve

Comment: Have you tried $y=4\sin^2t$?

Comment: This substitution works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(x)=y(x)^2\sqrt{4-y(x)}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2\sqrt{4-y(x)}}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2\sqrt{4-y(x)}}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2\sqrt{4-y(x)}}\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}$$

---

Solving the integral, substitute $u=y(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\text{I}=\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2\sqrt{4-y(x)}}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{u^2\sqrt{4-u}}\space\text{d}u=$$

Now, substitute $s=4-u$ and $\text{d}s=-\space\text{d}u$ after that substitute $p=\sqrt{s}$ and $\text{d}p=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}\space\text{d}s$:

$$-\int\frac{1}{(s-4)^2\sqrt{s}}\space\text{d}s=-2\int\frac{1}{\left(p^2-4\right)^2}\space\text{d}p$$

Now use partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{\left(p^2-4\right)^2}=\frac{1}{32(p+2)}+\frac{1}{16(p+2)^2}-\frac{1}{32(p-2)}+\frac{1}{16(p-2)^2}$$

You'll find the solution:

$$\text{I}=\frac{\ln\left|\sqrt{4-y(x)}-2\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{4-y(x)}+2\right|}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{4-y(x)}}{4y(x)}$$

---

So, we ge the solution:

$$\frac{\ln\left|\sqrt{4-y(x)}-2\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{4-y(x)}+2\right|}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{4-y(x)}}{4y(x)}=x+\text{C}$$

To find $\text{C}$ we use $y(4)=2$:

$$\frac{\ln\left|\sqrt{4-2}-2\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{4-2}+2\right|}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{4-2}}{4\cdot2}=4+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{\sqrt{2}+\text{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{8}=4+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=-\frac{32+\sqrt{2}+\text{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{8}$$

So we get:

$$\frac{\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{4-y(x)}-2}{\sqrt{4-y(x)}+2}\right|}{16}-\frac{\sqrt{4-y(x)}}{4y(x)}=x-\frac{32+\sqrt{2}+\text{arccoth}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{8}$$